Make specific nested child scrollable using Tailwind
I have this example of a layout:
<div class="flex flex-col h-full">
    <div>
        This is the main nav
    </div>

    <Separator orientation="horizontal"/>

    <div class="flex h-full">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <button> 1 </button>
            <button> 2 </button>
        </div>

        <Separator orientation="vertical"/>

        <main class="max-w-md mx-auto">

            <h1> Content </h1>

            <div>
                <button> do one </button>
                <button> do two? </button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="overflow-y-auto">
                    <!-- This div element should be scrollable! -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </main>

    </div>

</div>

Currently, when the innermost child is getting very long/high, instead of this child being scrollable, the outermost parent becomes scrollable. I want the highlighted child to be scrollable. How do i accomplish this? I believe i dont understand some general things about relative height in flex and overflow mechanism, therefore, i would appreciate alot if this was being elaborated in the solution.
I tried many things similar to the code above, but nothing has worked...

If you want to make the innermost child scrollable while keeping the outermost parent fixed, you would have to ensure that the child element's height is constrained so that it can scroll within the available space:

Ensure that the parent container has a defined height so that the child can scroll within it.

Apply overflow-y-auto to the child that should be scrollable and make sure its height is constrained within the parent container.
You can also find this reference useful.


I have provided a code snippet to help:
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
    <div>
        This is the main nav
    </div>

    <Separator orientation="horizontal"/>

    <div class="flex flex-1 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <button> 1 </button>
            <button> 2 </button>
        </div>

        <Separator orientation="vertical"/>

        <main class="flex flex-col max-w-md mx-auto flex-1">
            <h1> Content </h1>

            <div>
                <button> do one </button>
                <button> do two? </button>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
                <!-- This div element should now be scrollable! -->
                <div>
                   <p> what if i like coding</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>



Just below the ‘, you write the class “h-full” for the div element. What is this height relative to? My experience is that it takes the parent height, and because of “This is the main nav” component, the mentioned child will outgrow its parent. Do you agree? OPS! I wrote this myself… but how would i prevent this from happening?

no worries at all, I have updated the code to prevent this, let us see what happens?

@ÓlavurNón does the above code help?

Thank you for your help, i’ll try tomorrow and let you know!:)

I managed to make this work! My real example is a bit more nested, and in there, i figured out, that you have to specify overflow-hidden on some elements. I would hope that the overflow-y-auto would first be checked, and then the elements would not have to overflow elsewhere.
